# Bind Property to Cosine JavaFX

Tags: javafx, binding

Currently property bindings available in JavafX are `.add()`, `.subtract()`, `.multiple()`, `negate()`, etc..
I would like to bind to a cosine of a double property (angle), something like

`myProperty().bind(cos(angleProperty).multiply(factorProperty));`

I can implement this with listening to changes in `angleProperty` and `factorProperty`, but wondering if I can make my own cos binding.

Answer (score 4):

You can do

```
myProperty().bind(Bindings.createDoubleBinding(() ->
    Math.cos(angleProperty.get()) * factorProperty.get(),
    angleProperty, factorProperty));
```

or

```
DoubleBinding height = new DoubleBinding() {
    {
         bind(angleProperty);
         bind(factorProperty);
    }
    @Override
    public double computeValue() {
         return Math.cos(angleProperty.get()) * factorProperty.get() ;
    }
};

myProperty().bind(height);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this library

https://github.com/lestard/advanced-bindings

which offers bindings to more math function than the standard JavaFX.